# A question about Game.currentGame.network.sendRPC

Tags: javascript

i was just looking thru some code and saw `Game.currentGame.network.sendRPC`. What is this, and what does it do? How do i use this?

If you know and help, Thank you!!

Have a good day peoples

Comment: Depends on what `Game` is.  I noticed you asked [this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671795/what-exactly-is-sendrpc).  I doubt you will get better answers unless you did some additional research that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: After 5 mins of research it appears that it's only visible in hack/cheat scripts for the game zombs.io.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok i will. Im very sorry i will edit my question

Comment: ive seen Game.currentGame.network.sendRpc() in youtube things too tho

Comment: Here are the references I found, if they are helpful [gold generation script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/389115-%C6%AD%C6%88-%F0%9D%94%BE%F0%9D%95%A0%F0%9D%95%9D%F0%9D%95%95-%F0%9D%94%BE%F0%9D%95%96%F0%9D%95%9F%F0%9D%95%96%F0%9D%95%A3%F0%9D%95%92%F0%9D%95%A5%F0%9D%95%A0%F0%9D%95%A3/code) [get info script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/381431-get-info/code)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.